# Django: model object related table not exist

Tags: python, django

It has been quite a while since I'd used MySQL DB using django ORM.
And When I tried to make a dump file so that I can move the data to another database, I figured out some one of the table were missing.

Below is the relevant code in mainapp.models.py

```py
class Review(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)
    title = models.TextField(blank=True)
    contents = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

I expected table 'mainapp_review' should be in the database but any query or execution related to this query didn't work saying it doesn't exist.
Also, 'show tables' command result confirmed mainapp_review is not there.

My question now is, if it is true, where those row data exist then?
And how django ORM has been able to do CRUD when there is no table for that?

Comment: Shortly after posting this question, I found that the data sits in User table instead.
Because I just used django ORM as it makes things a lot simpler for me although what I was doing actually didn't require any web features, I never checked User table before.
It looks somehow django ORM mapped to different table when I copy/pasted old code here and there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data might be different model instead the model that you are checking.I think you have other model in your web app , please check that table.